# Bound for variance of maximum of normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, inequality

Suppose that $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\mathbf{X}\sim N(\mathbf{0},\Sigma)$ is an $n$-dimensional normal random vector. I want to show the bound
$$ \text{Var}\left(\max_{i\leq n} X_i\right)\leq \max_{i\leq n} \text{Var}(X_i)$$
How do I even begin showing this type of bound?

Comment: Are the $X_i$ independent? With common $\sigma$, or differing $\sigma_i$? Presumably you intend the latter by your notation $Var(X_i)$?